# Element in sticky menu getting pushed down on scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, sticky

Hi :) I am a bit intimated to post here but I am at my wit's end.

I am using wordpress and a theme - Cake - for a company website.

I am trying to position a dynamic button to align with the wordpress menu in a sticky wrapper (.menu_wrapper). No matter what i do - float, display, etc - the button is jumping slightly upon scroll. The code is in the right place but I can't assign this button the same class as the wordpress menu items - this is a limitation ( I think). I would prefer to be able to keep this in place with just CSS.

I'm a self-taught, learn as I go, thrown into this person and am doing my best. I know this place is full of actual coders and experts which is why I am reaching out :)

**The CSS for the .login_button is**

```
.login_button {  
    display:inline !important;
    margin-top: 38px !important;
    float: left !important;  
    background:#e73f3a !important;
    color:White !important;
    font-family:roboto !important;
    font-size:22px !important;
    }
```

You can see this problem at play here: https://netterrain.com - it's the LOG IN button in red.

I really really appreciate any help anyone can offer. Thank you :)

Comment: I'd remove the !important on them, it's not ideal to use it as you get into specificity wars when you try to override the rule. The div with an id of Top_bar gets assigned a class of `is-sticky` when you scroll, so you could have a second rule that is something like: `#Top_bar.is-sticky .login_button { margin-top: 12px; }` or however you want it to look, which would override the default 38px it has. You have responsive triggers too so you may need to add a few rules. Hope that helps you on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the initial `margin-top` whose value is 38px should be changed to 13px when you start scrolling.

You need to add another class to the button when scrolling:

you can achieve this using javascript:

```
// on scroll, 
$(window).on('scroll',function(){

        $('.login_button').addClass('is-scrolling');
});
```

And in your css add this:

```
.login_button is .login_button .is-scrolling{

    margin-top: 13px !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! I very much appreciate your help, Yahya! Thank you!

Comment: Gald ıt could help :)